# C++ Compute prime factors of a number and print them

Tags: c++

I want to ask the user for an integer, and print the prime factors.
Example: User enters 100, program displays 2 2 5 5

So far I have the following:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void factors(int n){

int z = 2;

while (z * z <= n)
{
    if (n % z == 0)
    {   
        cout << z;
        n = (n / z);
    }
    else
    {
        z++;
    }
}
if (n > 1)
    {cout << n << "\n";}
}
int main()
{

int x;

cout << "Input positive integer greater than 1: ";

cin >> x;

factors(x);
cout << "The result: " << x;
return 0;}
```

My question is how do I get my main function to communicate with the factors procedure. I run the program, I get the message asking for input, I input 12, I get the message "The result" but with a number of 25, and also 12, the number that the user input. it's like the program is avoiding my factors(int n) procedure. Help with the syntax please?!?

My issue is with the syntax I think.
Because I found the following function to help with listing prime factors:
[Finding prime factors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11924249/finding-prime-factors?newreg=b54bad3fa58f42c28b3c253c17a90ac2)
-user44810

```
define factors(n)

z = 2

while (z * z <= n)

    if (n % z == 0)
        output z
        n /= z

    else
        z++

if n > 1
    output n
```

Thank you!!!

Comment: Do not add tags for different, unrelated languages! And fo rma t yo ur q ues tio n pr o p er ly!.

Comment: The code you found earlier is psuedo code which means that it doesn't necessarily follow the correct syntax for any language, it is just to help with understanding the process the code should follow.

Comment: Thanks, my interpretation of the pseudocode is at the top of the program. It will not return a correct result, however.

Comment: @IglooJitsu Please notice that you are not allowed to deface your own question. When posting it, you irrevocably licensed it to Stack Exchange under the CC BY SE license. Further attempts to deface your own question may result in a moderator locking it.

Comment: The source formatting is poor.  If I was marking your work, I would give it 'F-'  w/o bothering testing/reading it further, and move on to the next submission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the biggest issue is that there is a missing brace at the end of your factors function. you need to add another brace after the if (n > 1) brace. Also, there is a missing semicolon at the end of the last cout that will throw an error.

Another issue that won't prevent the code from running is that when you print "The result: " << x you will be giving the same value as the user input.

If you want your main function to print out the result from factors() at that spot, then the function needs to return the data instead of printing it. To fix this, the factors function can be made to return a string with the output you want:

```
//return a string with the output
string factors(int n){

//create a string to save the output to
string factorlist = "";
int z = 2;

while (z * z <= n)
{
    if (n % z == 0)
    {   
        //append z to the end of the string and add a space to make it easier to read
        factorlist+=to_string(z)+" ";
        n = (n / z);
    }
    else
    {
        z++;
    }
}
if (n > 1)
{
//append n to the end of the string and add a newline
factorlist+=to_string(n)+"\n";
}
//output the string factorlist to wherever the function was called from
return factorlist;
}
```

then on the lines that look like:

```
factors(x);
cout << "The result: " << x
```

Should be:

```
cout << "The result: " << factors(x);
```

Currently, you are just printing out the value of x that the user input. If you want to save the value of factors(x) you would need to set a variable equal to it like this:

```
string FactorsResult = factors(x)
```

And then print it; or, as in the corrected code above, just print it directly in the cout statement.

Comment: Thanks for helping me. Using:

`cout << "The result: " << factors(x);`

I get an error: no match for "operator<<'

Sorry, I'm also having some trouble with formatting these comments. Working on it!

Comment: Hopefully this edit fixes everything that I missed earlier

Comment: I fixed the missing brace and missing semicolon problem, and now the issue is that I am getting an error @ this part of the code: `cout << "the result: " << factors(x);` It says there is no match for "operator<<" in ostream, specifically the "<<" right before `factors(x)`

Comment: Oops, that is also my bad. The function you have is a void function so it does not return any sort of data. If you want it to work that way, the function would need to return something. I will edit my answer again.

Comment: I tried changing the `void` type to `int`, now the program runs, however when I input the number `12`, The output is: `Input positive integer greater than 1: 12                                                                                                                                         
223                                                                                                                                                                               
The result: 6295968` I see the prime factors 223 at least! Making progress...

Comment: I blocked out `/*cout << "The result: " <<*/` and am now able to input a value like 50, and the program outputs 255. Do you know how I am able to add a single space between each factor output? Thanks in advance buddy..

Comment: is your factor function returning a string or an int?

Comment: It looks like this: `int factors(int n)`

Comment: because you are returning an integer, you can't have spaces in it. If you change the function to return a string type like the example above you can add spaces between the numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<int> factors(int n){

vector<int> result;
int z = 2;

while (z * z <= n)
{
    if (n % z == 0)
    {   
        result.push_back(z);
        n = (n / z);
    }
    else
    {
        z++;
    }
}
if (n > 1)
    result.push_back(z);
return result;
}

int main()
{

int x;

cout << "Input positive integer greater than 1: ";

cin >> x;

vector<int> result_factors = factors(x);
cout << "The result: ";
for (int i: result_factors)
  cout << "i  ";
cout << endl;

return 0;
}
```

I changed your `factor()` function to output nothing on `cout` but saving the factors in a vector and returning it. In the main function, iterate over the result vector and print the values to `cout`.

Comment: I appreciate the help. I need to read up on the vector header first, this is the first time I've come across it! Have only gone over functions and loops so far in my CSE 201 course.