# How to make a factor generator of a whole number?

Tags: c++, loops, generator, factors

I'm trying to make a factor generator for any number, and I'm starting off with creating something that gathers all numbers of the "num" variable, and adding each number of the "num" variable to another vector `numbersOfN`, so I can later on divide that by something to get the possible factors.

At the moment I'm stuck on why `numbersOfN.size()` doesn't work properly as it keeps repeating, could you show me an alternative or a way to quickly fix this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


void getFactors(int num)
{
    int n = num;
    int nofn;
    std::vector<int> factorsOfN(n);
    std::vector<int> numbersOfN(n);
    n = numbersOfN.size();

    for (nofn = 1; nofn <= n; nofn++)
    {
        numbersOfN.push_back(nofn);
        for (int j = 1; j < numbersOfN.size(); j++)
        {
            std::cout << numbersOfN.at(j) << " ";
        }
    }

}

int main()
{
    int num = 32;
    getFactors(num);
}
```

Comment: `std::vector<int> numbersOfN(n);` creates an `vector` with `n` elements, all 0, and `numbersOfN.push_back(nofn);` adds `nofn` at the end of the array. Do you mean `numbersOfN[nofn] = nofn;`? Don't forget that indexes start with 0, not with 1 and end at n-1, not n.

Comment: *"it doesn't work when I get the 'numbersOfN' vector .size() properly as it keeps repeating"* -- This is close to a good description of your issue, but what exactly do you get as the `size()` and what did you expect?

Comment: It would be good to focus your code a bit more. Keep in mind that your goal here is to demonstrate the problem with `.size()`, not to demonstrate "a factor generator". Instead of trying to print the elements of `numbersOfN`, would it be enough to print its size? (Also, you might as well remove the unused `factorsOfN` from this *example* code.)

Comment: Sorry, but it sounds like you have no clue how to find the "factors" for a number. There is no point in making a vector of numbers 1, ..., n. See e.g. here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11924249/finding-prime-factors

Comment: Your loop goes "add 1 to the vector, then print all the numbers except the first, then add 2 to the vector, then print all numbers except the first, then add 3 to the vector, then print all numbers except the first, ...". I'm pretty sure that that's not what you meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A much simpler version of what you are after:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> getFactors(int num) {
    std::vector<int> factors;

    for (int i = 1; i*i <= num; i++) {
        if ((num % i) == 0) {
            factors.push_back(i);
            int j = num / i;
            if (i != j) {
                factors.push_back(j);
            }
        }           
    }

    return factors;
}

int main() {
    int num = 32;
    std::vector<int> factors = getFactors(num);
    for (int f : factors) {
        std::cout << f << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```